# limit or restrict math operands of mathjax

Tags: mathjax

I have a web tool that should allow my users to define their own formulas based on a very restricted set of operators:
"- + * / -"

some "group operators":
"MAX(a,b,c,d) MIN(a,b,c,d) AVG(a,b,c,d) MAX_T(a,b) MIN_T(a,b) AVG_T(a,b) DELTA_T(a,b)"

and parenthesis are allowed.

Numbers as well as variable names are allowed as operands.

Is there a way to prevent users from using symbols not in the set of operators and operands I listed above? 
I'm not seeing anything related to this in the documentation

Comment: No, there's no build-in way for this. While you can disable macros by overloading them, you can't really disable the core TeX macros without negative side effects. You're probably better off writing you own toTeX or toMathML converter. The asciimath input might be a useful example.